# Array limits in Azure templates limited to 100 entries?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to deploy ipRules for storageAccount to add Azure Devops IP ranges and it looks like IP rule is limited to 100 entries in array and after that it starts to throw exceptions like below.

`Code=InvalidValuesForRequestParameters; Message=Values for request parameters are invalid: networkAcls.ipRules[].`

```
{
                            "value": "13.67.128.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.144.0/21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.152.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.153.0/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.153.32/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.153.64/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.153.128/25"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.155.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.156.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.160.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.67.192.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.86.0.0/17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "13.89.0.0/16"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.37.128.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.38.96.0/23"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.38.122.0/23"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.40.192.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.44.8.0/21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.184.64.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.186.192.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "20.190.134.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "23.99.128.0/17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "23.100.80.0/21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "23.100.240.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "23.101.112.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "23.102.202.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.67.160.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.69.128.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.0.0/17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.161.64/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.166.192/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.175.192/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.175.240/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.182.16/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.182.192/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.184.128/25"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.197.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.77.255.128/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.78.128.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.78.221.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.82.16.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.82.96.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.0.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.16.0/21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.24.0/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.24.64/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.24.128/25"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.25.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.26.0/23"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.28.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.83.32.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.86.0.0/17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.87.180.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.89.224.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.16.0/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.128.16/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.129.224/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.130.64/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.132.192/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.137.224/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.140.96/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.140.224/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.141.0/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.142.128/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.142.240/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.144.0/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.144.128/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.148.176/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.149.96/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.151.160/27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.154.64/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.90.156.192/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.113.192.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.122.16.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.122.32.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.122.64.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.122.128.0/17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "40.126.6.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.108.208.0/21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.109.8.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.114.128.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.125.128.0/22"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.136.30.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.141.192.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.141.240.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.143.193.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.143.224.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.154.0.0/18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.154.128.0/17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.158.160.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.158.192.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.0.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.32.0/20"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.48.0/28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.49.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.56.0/21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.64.0/19"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.96.0/21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.104.0/25"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.165.128.0/17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "52.176.128.0/19"
                        },
```

Comment: where is the question? create 2 arrays

Comment: How do I add 2 arrays to IPRules object? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2018-07-01/storageaccounts

Comment: `"ipRules": "[concat(arr1, arr2)]"`? if this property doesnt support more than 100 rules - nothing you can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage account resource provider in Azure has a limit of 100 IP network rules. Not necessarily a limitation of the ARM template itself but the resource provider that is being created or modified.

"Each storage account supports up to 100 IP network rules, which may be combined with Virtual network rules."
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range

Comment: It's 200 now in 2023.